# How can I remove a branch from the master branch in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have mistakenly merged a branch in master and now want to remove it. How can I do this in Visual Studio without using Git code commands? I want to keep the branch after removing it from master. Thank you

Comment: this question is fairly common on stackoverflow. Try the [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=undo+a+git+merge) function and see if the answer you seek is there

Comment: Please read [ask] and mention your Visual Studio version and the Git UI you use, as well as what you have tried. In my experience, the VS Gut UI is only good for committing, everything else is better done using the command line or another UI.

Comment: Most likely you can simply create a new branch from the top commit merged in (to get that branch back if you deleted it), and then reset local master to before the merge. But we need more info to know if that gets you what you want: Is this local only or has it been pushed to the remote already? Are there new commits after the merge on master that you want to keep? Why don't you want to use the command line? (Some things can't be done in VS, like reverting a merge commit for example.)